# correct horizon in 360 rectilinear video

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, distort

I recently got a 360 camera (samsung gear 360) with 2 fisheye lenses, wich are stitched together pretty good in the propriatary Samsung video editor to rectiliniar video. What does not work is a straight horizon :( i know adobe premiere can fix this called roll pan tilt of a 360 video, but i cant afford that, cause student + closed source windows only. So is there a way to correct this in Blender? i've used blender before to cut videos and that works pretty good, but i don't have any idea on this. I know similar things have been asked before, but those answers are over 2 years old and don't quite fit my use case.

tl:dr correct horizon in 360 video to be orthogonal to player

thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think that you would have to wrap the rectilinear image onto a world texture using emission, then change orientation with the Mapping node. Use Cycles and reduce samples to 1 for speed. Cycles supports rectilinear rendering. I have tried this before but not rotation around x axis only z.